# bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction and purpose of "scriptPubKey"?

Tags: createrawtransaction

I am playing with P2SH on regtest and try to understand the logic of creating and signing tx with bitcoin daemon. I am on version 0.15.1, and try to create a tx.

The used  scriptPubKey results from a simple if/else/endif statement, not from a standard multisig approach. So I manually created the redeem script, and turned it into an address (beginning with "2"). I then created a transaction, that funds this address. Now I want to spend these funds. While creating the transaction, I discovered that the usage of "scriptPubKey" does not change anything in my output.

Example without "scriptPubKey":

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest createrawtransaction '''[{"txid":"'b5b67997f36627a461cd5ee1951aa775a68faa0c11c50b8f068ea1c7f4a9b087'","vout":'0'}]''' '''{"'mgpe9b44YYYbhDE1dbWosCSQDPYFkkoHjt'":'9.99995000'}''' 
020000000187b0a9f4c7a18e068f0bc5110caa8fa675a71a95e15ecd61a42766f39779b6b50000000000ffffffff0178b69a3b000000001976a9140e507731ec9a94d454424f3ca65917a2abb45f4988ac00000000
```

Example with "scriptPubKey":

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest createrawtransaction '''[{"txid":"'b5b67997f36627a461cd5ee1951aa775a68faa0c11c50b8f068ea1c7f4a9b087'","vout":'0',"scriptPubKey":"'a914d53c738d730d8623eb2a070833599157beb3f6f687'"}]''' '''{"'mgpe9b44YYYbhDE1dbWosCSQDPYFkkoHjt'":'9.99995000'}'''
020000000187b0a9f4c7a18e068f0bc5110caa8fa675a71a95e15ecd61a42766f39779b6b50000000000ffffffff0178b69a3b000000001976a9140e507731ec9a94d454424f3ca65917a2abb45f4988ac00000000
```

The result is exactly the same. When the result is the same, what is the purpose of using this field as a parameter to "createrawtransaction"?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that scriptPubkey required when you create a raw transaction.
https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#createrawtransaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the create raw transaction method only uses the `txid` and `vout` parameters from that argument. You can view the relevant part of the source [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpc/rawtransaction.cpp#L384).

For all practical purposes, you could pass in `00` for the scriptPubKey and still get the same result.

Comment: You are right, I've been working with all addresses types and I've never attached it. so yes, it's totally not required. you don't even have to pass anything.

Comment: Yup, this was also my assumption, based on my tests (and perception). It’s just that I am not good enough in understanding the sources - and I am not comfortable with the „code is documentation“ approach... thx for confirmation!

Comment: @pebwindcraft Where did you even read about passing a scriptPubKey argument there? As far as I can see this is not mentioned anywhere; not in the code, not in the RPC help, and not on the developer documentation on bitcoin.org. There simply is no such field, expected or used in any way.

Comment: @PieterWuille Looks like it was mentioned in some issues/examples years ago, and a bunch of tutorials now just copy that: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/6483, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/35750/7272

Comment: @RaghavSood Ah, I see. I think it's just `signrawtransaction` that need `scriptPubKey` (when the UTXO is not known to wallet or node), and people simplify things and pass the same argument to `createrawtransaction` as well - but it has never had any use there.

Comment: @ PieterWuille (and all): indeed, also with the current daemon (v0.16.0) "bitcoin-cli -help createrawtransaction" there is nothing mentioned with "scriptPubKey" in the documentation. I surely used "older" posts. I thought I'd get an error when providing a wrong parameter, just to find out that the above example returns no error. I also tried to provide "scripPubKey_xyz" or "scriptPubKey_abc", or several other parameters. "bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction" would not through an error on these wrong or useless keyword parameters.